# Как связать 3 таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Здравствуйте.
У меня имеется 3 таблицы в mysql
goods, group_name, remainders

в таблицах следующие столбцы
goods (id,group_id,name,description)
group_name (id,name)
remainders (goods_id,remainder)

нужно вывести на экран данные из всех трех таблиц (goods.id,group_name.name,goods.name,remainders.remainder)
где
goods.group.id=group_name.id и goods.id=remainders.goods_id

пыталась сделать select из трех таблиц, но не вышло.

```
select 
  goods.id, 
  group_name.name, 
  goods.name, 
  remainders.remainder 
from 
   goods, 
   group_name, 
   remainders 
where 
   goods.group.id=group_name.id and 
   goods.id=remainders.goods_id
```

как правильно их объединить?

Comment: а как пытались?

Comment: select goods.id,group_name.name,goods.name,remainders.remainder from goods, group_name, remainders where goods.group.id=group_name.id and goods.id=remainders.goods_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да всего-то и делов, что перевести на аглицкий:

> нужно вывести на экран данные ... (goods.id,group_name.name,goods.name,remainders.remainder)

```
SELECT goods.id,group_name.name,goods.name,remainders.remainder
```

> из всех трех таблиц

```
FROM goods, group_name, remainders
```

> где goods.group.id=group_name.id и goods.id=remainders.goods_id

```
WHERE goods.group.id=group_name.id AND goods.id=remainders.goods_id
```

ИТОГО:

```
SELECT goods.id,group_name.name,goods.name,remainders.remainder
FROM goods, group_name, remainders
WHERE goods.group.id=group_name.id AND goods.id=remainders.goods_id
```

Comment: ай, все ок. грамматическая ошибка у меня WHERE goods.group.id вместо WHERE goods.group_id